# Firebase function equivalent in Supabase

Tags: supabase

I want to be able to write a function in TypeScript and have it run when a user is created (probably when an insert event occurs on the auth table)

I don’t want to author this in plpgsql

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

- You can create a trigger that calls an edge function.
- You can create the function using [PLV8](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/plv8) (Javascript).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.telegram_on_new_user() 
RETURNS trigger 
security definer 
set search_path public, auth, extensions 
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$ 
BEGIN 
-- Passing the email address to the function
PERFORM http_get('https://xxxx.functions.supabase.co/telegram-bot?email=' || new.email);
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$$; 

CREATE TRIGGER new_user_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON auth.users 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.telegram_on_new_user();
```

You can read more about how to [create webhooks](https://blog.mansueli.com/automating-webhooks-supabase-postgresql-guide) in Supabase in my blog.